# Unity MissingComponentException: There is no 'GameObject' attached to the "BG" game object, but a script is trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть GameObject BG , хочу что бы при изменении Toggle он отключался.

```
    private GameObject BG;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    BG = GetComponent<GameObject>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}

public void SetTheme(bool newValue)
{
    BG.SetActive(!BG.activeSelf);
}
```

Но этот код не работает. Дает такую ошибку:

MissingComponentException: There is no 'GameObject' attached to the "BG" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a GameObject to the game object "BG". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

Хотя в проекте есть Panel BG

Comment: А этот скрипт висит у  вас на объекте BG?

Answer (score 0):

Вы немного не так  записали что то в BG.
Если скрипт висит на BG  то нет нужны получать значение gameОjbject  через GetComponent<>
Вам достаточно просто использовать gameObject  вместо

```
 BG = GetComponent<GameObject>();
```

Дальше везде вы можете использовать просто gameObject  а не BG
 К примеру 
Было

```
BG.SetActive(!BG.activeSelf);
```

Стало

```
gameObject.SetActive(!gameObject.activeSelf);
```

Answer (score 0):

GameObject Это не компонент попробуйте в Start(); Написать так.

```
void Start() {
   BG = GameObject.Find("Имя объекта которой вы контролируете");
}
```